# Laravel - 2 divs by each other, one to the next row if not enough space

Tags: laravel, responsive

I have a page that displays a lot of divs, in 2 by x grid.. this is the code:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-around" >
@foreach(auth()->user()->galleries as $gallery)
        <div class="col-5
                    mb-5
                    p-3
                    rounded-lg
                    shadow
                    d-flex
                    justify-content-between
                    align-items-baseline
                    "                
             style="background-color: lightgrey;
                 background-size: 100%;
                 background-position: center;">
            <div class="w-75">
                <div class="">
                    <h2>{{$gallery->galname}}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    SOME CONTENT...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-auto">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around p-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="window.location='/gallery/{{ $gallery->id }}'">View / Edit</button>
                </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

So far it works great, but if i reduce the size of the browser or watch it on a cellphone, then they squish toghether.. I would like it to be responsive and jump to the next row if there is not enoguh space available.. so the 2 by x becomes a 1 by 2x table... how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add classes for the responsive design after `col-5`, i.e. `col-sm-10` which will change the size of the div in small screens.

```
.... class="col-5 col-sm-10 mb-5 ...
```

[more info here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)